# Can't show get_term output on the frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

So i try to show a custom taxonomy on the frontend.
The custom taxonomy is from a plugin i use and is called wcs-instructor.
I just want to show a Single Page with the content of the taxonomy by listing the names and images of the Instructors, the image is a custom field.

When i try to Query the taxonomy with get_term or with WP_Term_Query everything shows up nicely as long as im logged in with my Admin Account (havent actually tested another account).
When i log out and open the Page again its blank.

The structur is as follows.
Custom Taxonomy: wcs-instructor
Page Endpoint: /trainer
Custom Single page: page-trainer.php

```
get_header();
?>

<main id="primary" class="site-main">

<?php
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'trainer' );

endwhile; 

?>
</main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

content-trainer.php (striped some html thats unnecessary)

```
<div class="content">
    
        
        <?php  
        
        $term_query = new WP_Term_Query( 
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'wcs-instructor',) );

        if ( ! empty( $term_query->terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $term_query ->terms as $term ) {
                echo $term->name;
            }} 
            else {
                echo 'No term found.';
            }   
            ?>

</div>
```

I know that the code above only gives me the results that are not empty, but the taxonomy got entries that aren't.
Also the Code below also doesn't work.

```
<?php
        
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'wcs-instructor',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );
        

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
        {
            echo $term->term_id;
            echo '<br>';
            echo $term->name;
        }

        ?>
```

And i just cant find the reason why because when i go to /wcs-instructor/testinstructor i can view the content even when im not logged in.

Any hints on how to debug this behavior or why it's behaving like this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like that taxonomy might have the [`publicly_queryable`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) arg set to `false`. Not sure which plugin you are using to manage your custom taxonomies but the [CPT UI Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) has a setting for that argument.

[The Public Queryable setting for taxonomies in CPT UI plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02KYd.png)